# Funciones variables en javascript

Tags: javascript

En PHP tenemos las [funciones variables](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.variable-functions.php), que basicamente permiten hacer esto entre otras cosas

```
class Bar
{

    function __construct($foo)
    {
        $this->{'funcion' . $foo}();
    }

    private function funcionHola()
    {
        echo "Hola!";
    }

    private function funcionAdios()
    {
        echo "Adios!";
    }
}

$barHola = new Bar('Hola');
echo "<br />";
$barAdios = new Bar('Adios');
```

Y nos imprimirá esto:

```
Hola!
Adios!
```

¿Existe forma de hacer esto en javascript? Osea llamar dinamicamente a una función o método

Tengo este código en javascript, y en `load()` quiero llamar a la función variable

```
(function(window, document) {
  'use strict';

  var Bar = {
    load: function(foo) {
      // Llamar a la función variable
    },

    funcionHola: function() {
      console.log('Hola');
    },

    funcionAdios: function() {
      console.log('Adios');
    }
  };

  Bar.load('Hola');
  Bar.load('Adios');
}(window, window.document));
```

Comment: Dependiendo el scope puedes llamar a una función mediante su nombre, digamos que estas en el scope global podrías llamarla con `window['nombredelafuncion']()`;

Comment: Si funcionó con eso @Gerardo! Por alguna razón `window['función' + variable]()` no funciona, pero `this['funcion' + variable]()` si. Si quieres puedes ponerlo como respuesta para poder marcarla como aceptada

Comment: Bueno estas utilizando acento es por eso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo dependiendo el scope que este utilizando para llamar a la función, suponiendo que estamos dentro de un scope global podrías utilizar:

`window['nombredelafuncion']();` reemplazando `nombredelafuncion` por una variable string con el nombre de la función que deseas llamar.

Comment: @Andrus Diaz, tu edición parece un intento de respuesta en la respuesta de otro usuario, te sugiero que si deseas aportar lo hagas en una respuesta por separado

Answer (score 4):

En este caso, puedes llamar a tus funciones a través de `this['funcion' + foo]();` porque las funciones las tienes dentro de un scope, en este caso el objeto.

Por lo tanto, estas funciones solo están definidas dentro del scope del objeto, y no en el scope global de la aplicación. Puedes intentar llamar a una de estas funciones directamente fuera del objeto y verás como no te deja si no haces referencia al objeto (scope) que las contiene.

Mediante la palabra reservada `this` haces referencia al propio objeto ya que lo estás llamando dentro del mismo.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
(function(window, document) {
  'use strict';

  var Bar = {
    load: function(foo) {  
      this['funcion' + foo]();
    },

    funcionHola: function() {
      console.log('Hola');
    },

    funcionAdios: function() {
      console.log('Adios');
    }
  };

  Bar.load('Hola');
  Bar.load('Adios');
}(window, window.document));
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var myFunc = {

    'funOne': function(){

         return "this is funOne";

    },

    'funTwo': function() {
        return " this is fun two;
    }
}
```

Luego la llamas:

```
var x = myFunc['funOne'];
```

En tu caso sería así:

```
var x = Bar['funcionHola'];
```

También puedes ver este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48398461/9015852)